# Evaluating Trigonometric Integral with complex analysis

Tags: integration, residue-calculus

I have an integral of the following form:$$
\int \frac{d\phi}{A+B\sin(\phi)+C\sin^2\phi+D\cos^2\phi}
$$
To evaluate this explicitly result in a form that isn't useful for any particular progress. I have been mentioned the method of resides to best approach this sort of integral, i.e $$I=\int^{2\pi}_0 f(\phi,\sin\phi,\cos\phi) 
$$
How does one use the residue theorem from complex analysis in order to obtain a 'different' form than that seen by placing the integral inside WolframAlpha

Comment: So do you want your integral to be from $0$ to $2\pi$?

Comment: Note you can replace $+D \cos^2 \phi $ with $+D(1-\sin^2 \phi) $ and absorb this fourth term into the constant and $C \sin^2 \phi$ terms.

Comment: And following on from Coffeemath's comment, that would render the denominator as a quadratic in $\sin \phi$ and letting $u=\sin \phi$ may allow you to either factorise or see a nice trig substitution for evaluation of the integral.

Answer (score 2):

As @Coffeemath suggested, let $\phi=\sin^{-1}(x)$ to get
$$I=\int \frac {dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}\,\, \left( (c-d)x^2+b x+(a+d) \right)}$$ Assuming that $c\neq d$, rewrite it as
$$I=\frac 1{c-d}\int \frac {dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}  (x-r)(x-s)}$$ where $(r,s)$ are the roots of the quadratic.

Use partial fraction decomposition
$$\frac 1{ (x-r)(x-s)}=\frac 1{r-s}\left(\frac 1{x-r} -\frac 1{x-s}\right)$$ So, you now face two integrals
$$I=\int \frac {dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}\,(x-t)}$$

Use Euler substitution to obtain a single arctangent function.